# Clean URLs not working

Tags: 8

I just have Drupal 7 and 8 installed in my localhost on Opensuse Leap. With Drupal 7 I cannot pass the clean urls test, however the site is completely functional. By clicking the links on the menu I can access `localhost/drupal7/?q=admin/dashboard` or `localhost/drupal7/?q=admin/people` (for example).

In Drupal 8 I can access the front page `localhost/drupal8` but when I click some link, for example "Log in", I'm redirected to `localhost/htdocs/drupal8/user/login`. And I get an Apache 404 error. I don't understand why the server redirects to another directory when both installations are using the same configuration file.

I already tried all drupal.org apache-related tutorials without success.

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: What is your Apache configuration? Is mod_rewrite enabled and an AllowOverride set on the Drupal directory?

Comment: @cilefen mod_rewrite is enabled. When I put following code: `<Directory /srv/www/htdocs>
  AllowOverride All
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</Directory>` in httpd.conf.local I get an 403 error for the whole site (forbidden access).

Comment: You should only need AllowOverride All, and let Drupal's .htaccess handle the redirect. The .htaccess is there, yes?

Comment: @cilefen .htaccess is there. Have tried with your proposed solution. Same result.

Comment: @cilefen I put a garbage string in .htaccess to check if the host was even reading it and I got an error 500, so the .htaccess file was ok. When I erased the string and saved the file again, the site magically started to work. That was weird, but finally I got my site running. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well moving to opensuse leap from another distribution.  There was more than one problem.

1. Even if rewrite_module is listed in loadmodule.conf, this file is not not read without a change to httpd.conf.  You can check if the module is loaded with

   apache2ctl -M
2. As is posted elsewhere Options and AllowOverride arguments need to be placed within the relevant Directory tags.
3. If there is a subdirectory of the webserver, there needs to be a RewriteBase argument given in the .htaccess file.

#### Try this to get things working:

**In file /etc/apache2/default-server.conf**

Within the `<Directory>` tags add or edit the Options and AllowOverride lines to

```
Options All
AllowOverride All
```

**In file /etc/apache2/loadmodule.conf add**

```
LoadModule rewrite_module    /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_rewrite.so
```

**In file /etc/apache2/httpd.conf uncomment the IfDefine tags**

```
#<IfDefine !SYSCONFIG>
  Include /etc/apache2/loadmodule.conf
#</IfDefine>
```

**In file /srv/www/htdocs/NAMEOFYOURSUBDIRECTORYHERE/.htaccess add a line**

```
RewriteBase /NAMEOFYOURSUBDIRECTORYHERE
```

**Check if the configuration file "Syntax is OK."**

It will probably complain that some modules have already been loaded, but that's alright.

```
 apache2ctl configtest
```

**Restart Apache**

```
systemctl stop apache2; sleep 5; systemctl start apache2
```